# Transform schedule to comprehensive report with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to turn a schedule with the following format into a report format.

Currently the data is stored as follows:

```
Person Name    Jun 1    Jun 2    Jun 3   Jun 4   Jun 5   Jun 6   Jun 7   Jun 8   Jun 9   Jun 10   ...
John Smith       X        X        X       X       O       O       O       X       X       X      ...
Aaron Roberts    O        O        X       X       X       X       O       O       O       O      ...
Jess Lewis       O        O        O       O       X       X       X       X       X       X      ...
Edgar Blue       X        X        X       X       X       O       O       O       O       X      ...
Lara Irvin       X        X        O       O       O       O       X       X       X       X      ...
```

The X represent days that they're "ON" and the O represent days that they're off.

What I want is to run a python script that summarizes the schedule in a report of this format:

```
Person Name          From:          To:
John Smith           Jun 1          Jun 4
John Smith           Jun 8          Jun 10
Aaron Roberts        Jun 3          Jun 6
Jess Lewis           Jun 5          Jun 10
Edgar Blue           Jun 1          Jun 5
Edgar Blue           Jun 10         Jun 13
Lara Irvin           Jun 1          Jun 2
Lara Irvin           Jun 7          Jun 10
```

What I've tried is to create a unique names list

```
names = ["John Smith", "Aaron Roberts", "Jess Lewis", "Edgar Blue", "Lara Irvin"]
```

And then do

```
for name in names:
    df.iloc["Person Name"] == name
```

Then I'm not sure how to proceed, I'm trying to look if the i position is an X or an O, then look if the i-1 position is an X or an O

Then...

```
if i == "X" && i-1 == "O"
```

Populate that header date in the other table's "From:" column

and...

```
if == "O" && i-1 == "X"
```

Populate that header date in the other table's "To:" column

Then repeat the same process using a nested for loop across all "Person Name" and all dates.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will need the `cumsum` create the subgroup then we stack , `groupby` with `agg`

```
df=df.set_index('PersonName')

s1=df.eq('O').cumsum(1).stack().reset_index()

s=s1[df.stack().ne('O').values].groupby(['PersonName',0])['level_1'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)

s
              first   last
PersonName                
AaronRoberts   Jun3   Jun6
EdgarBlue      Jun1   Jun5
EdgarBlue     Jun10  Jun10
JessLewis      Jun5  Jun10
JohnSmith      Jun1   Jun4
JohnSmith      Jun8  Jun10
LaraIrvin      Jun1   Jun2
LaraIrvin      Jun7  Jun10
```